# HTextView работа с шрифтом и со String

Tags: java, android, строки, textview, шрифты

Недавно начал заниматься в Android Studio, постоянно обращаюсь для решения вопросов на этот ресурс, однако сейчас я ответа - не нашел.

Задача - вывести сообщение в HTextView с использованием другого шрифта и используя String.

Проблема - при запуске активности приложение останавливается с ошибкой.

Могу предположить, что проблема связана с неверно написанным кодом в активности, или невозможности работать HTextView c объявленным шрифтом и/или String.

Код прилагаю:

---

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.hanks.htextview.HTextView;

public class Start_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
HTextView hTextView;
HTextView PixelText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.start_layout);

    PixelText = (HTextView) findViewById(R.id.HTextViewAppStart);
    Typeface CustomPixelText = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "pixel.ttf");
    PixelText.setTypeface(CustomPixelText);

    hTextView = (HTextView) findViewById(R.id.HTextViewAppStart);
    hTextView.animateText(getString(R.string.AppStart));

    CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(5500,1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Start_Activity.this, Menu_Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }.start();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // запрет возврата к предыдущему окну
}
```

}

---

```
<com.hanks.htextview.HTextView
    xmlns:htext="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/HTextViewAppStart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    htext:animateType="typer"
    />
```

---

log ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Без логов ошибки и указания на какой строке она возникает - как вам помочь?

Comment: log ошибки - добавил.

Comment: Ошибку надо не скрином а тестом. Плюс вы не указали на какой строке возникает.